# Responsive and absolute positioning

Tags: jquery

I need some help/idea for fixing this...

I have a PSD design. Size: 1504x1070

I have to make a HTML/CSS template with the same proportions. I've used a "rule of three" in jQuery to resize, and position elements based on my screen resolutions.

**The problem is** that the Image2 is over the Image1... and it should be under it.

I've set up this rule in my css, and the image height is resizing ok: max-width: 100%

This is my jquery code:

```
// Image1 width in PSD: 496 , height to top in PSD: 154
// Image2 width in PSD: 374 , height to top in PSD: 493
// Call for Image1 div container: calculateWidth(496); calculateTop(154)
// Same for Image2 div container.


function calculateWidth(px){
    var width = $(window).width();

    var design_width = 1504;

    var step1 = width * px;
    var step2 = step1 / design_width;

    return step2;
}

function calculateTop(px){
    var height = $(window).height();

    var design_height = 1070;

    var step1 = height * px;
    var step2 = step1 / design_height;

    return step2;
}
```

Any idea how to get this ?
Thanks!

**Edit:**
I've make a simple picture where you could see the problem:

http://cl.ly/image/3l2y0k1U2W2j

Comment: If over/under is the issue, can't you fix it with `z-index`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I cannot use z-index, i've edit the original message with the problem.